# Number of solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The number of solutions of $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y+1}{x-1}$$ when $y(1) = 2$ is

Options are **a)** none   **b)** one   **c)** two   **d)** infinite

Now this can be solved via variable separable method which gives me
$$\frac{dy}{y+1} = \frac{dx}{x-1}$$
And on integrating both sides I got,
$\log (y + 1) = \log(x - 1) + \log c$
which gave me
$y + 1 = c(x - 1)$
On putting the given values as $x = 1$ and $y = 2$ gives
$3 = 0$ or $c = \frac{3}{0}$ which means no solution.

I just want to ask if my solution is correct because the book gave the answer as one solution. I checked few other places and they for some reason are solving by integrating as
$\log (y + 1) = \log(x - 1) - \log c$
which of course would give them the desired one solution as $x = 1$.

I am confused.

Comment: How did you get $\log c$

Comment: How changing it to $-\ln c$ gives one answer? $y=\frac1c(x-1)-1$ don't have a solution for the initial condition

Comment: @AndrewLi arbitrary constant, if we have $c$, because $\ln$ is one to one we can set $\ln c_0=c$

Comment: In what class of functions you are looking for a solution? Obviously if $x=1$ and $y$ is not $-1$ we have a discontinuity in the first derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ill-posed since $x=1$ is a singular point. But even if you consider the given point to be a limit, you can see from the general solution that

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} y(x) = \lim_{x\to1} \big[c(x-1)-1 \big] = -1 $$

Clearly, there are no such functions where $\lim_{x\to1} y(x) = 2$

Answer (score 0):

Your general solution $y=c(x-1)-1$ is correct by direct check

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{y+1}{x-1}=\frac{c(x-1)-1+1}{x-1}=cx$$

but since the equation is defined for $x\neq 1$ we have no solution for this particular initial condition.

Comment: I think you mean $c$, instead of $cx$.

Comment: If he considers functions that have infitine derivatives there is a solution.

Answer (score -2):

If you consider $x(y)$ not $y(x)$ you'll get $x = 1 + (1 + y)\cdot c$, and therefore substituting $y=2$ you'll get $c=0$ if you want $x=1$. The solutions is therefore $x(y)=1$.

Edit: also mind that $\int dx/x=\ln|x|$.

Comment: That function is not invertible and therefore does not solve the original equation.

Comment: @Dylan original equation is not written in a form that uniquely  prescribes function and independent variable. You can flip it and be absolutely fine.

Comment: I disagree. $dy/dx$ clearly means $y$ is the dependent variable. You can flip it only if the function $y(x)$ is invertible.

Comment: @Dylan what's the difference from $1/(dx/dy)$? It doesn't matter whether function is invertable or not, differentials are not aware of those matters. If you had $d^{2}y/dx^{2}$ then yes, function and independent variables are clearly distinct.

Comment: $dy/dx$ is not a fraction. It's a first derivative of $y$ w.r.t $x$. Differentials are not involved here. The relation $dx/dy = (dy/dx)^{-1}$ only holds if and only if $y(x)$ is an invertible function.

Comment: Also, let's not forget that the initial condition clearly states $y(1) = 2$, *not* $x(2)=1$

Comment: @Dylan since he's interested in extensive search for solutions this is quite obvious approach.

Comment: The method is valid. The solution isn't.

Comment: @Dylan that’s not how it works.

Comment: Why not? Correct methods do not always lead to a solution. In this case, what you obtained cannot be expressed as a function of $x$, therefore it's not a valid solution. That *should* be your conclusion here.

Comment: @Dylan that’s only if you discard this solution on purpose. Relation between differentials and initial condition holds.

Comment: The equation isn't written in the form of differentials. It's a derivative, implying a function of $x$.

Comment: Just to be clear, we *should* discard this solution because it is not a function. It's just an extraneous solution you get when turning $dy/dx$ into $dx/dy$. It's like when you square the equation $x=2$ to $x^2=4$ to get an extraneous solution of $x=-2$

Comment: @Dylan flipping equation is not squaring one. And since initial condition is defined in $x=-1$ there's clearly no issues with zeroes in denominator so you can just multiply by it.